# Unable to understand $variable and how it works

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code

```
    var $slider = $('#divSlider')
                    .hover(function () {

                    }, function () {

                    }).appendTo('div');

    $('a').mouseover(function () {
        $slider
            .addClass('active')
    });
```

I have the following questions:

- What is $slider?
- When does it appendTo div, does it happen after hovering or instantly?
- In the mouseover function, $slider is used again. What does $slider contain?

Thanks

Comment: `$slider` is a variable that holds a jQuery object

Comment: This is a fundamentally-loaded question that is more than something you should just ask on SO.  If you understand Javascript itself and the basics of jQuery, this site might be useful:  http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *What is $slider?*

  In your context, It is just a `variable`.
- *When does it appendTo div, does it happen after hovering or instantly?*

  `#divSlider` will append to the div instantly and it will register `#divSlider` for hover events too.
  Finally the object which having details regarding the same will be assigned to that variable.
- *In the mouseover function, $slider is used again. What does $slider contain?*

  No, `$slider` will not be used while user is `hovering`. That variable just contains an object of #divSlider

Comment: I think you mentioned `hovering` when the user was asking about the `mouseover` event handler on the anchor. Good answers!

Answer (score 0):

- `$slider` is a variable that's set to a jQuery-wrapped `#divSlider` element
- It'll `appendTo` as soon as the code above is executed.
- `$slider` is simply a reference to `$('#divSlider')` so it can be used again. So `.addClass` will really be adding a class to the `#divSlider` element

Comment: so is $slider like a cached variable?

Comment: Yes, a variable. Variables hold things - `cached` sums it up as far as you're concerned but it's not really cache, it's a reference. It *refers* to the jquery-wrapped element we assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

- `$slider` is a simple variable which is equal to `$("#divSlider")`. There is no any special meaning of $ here. This is similar to `var slider = $("#divslider")`. No difference is there in both `slider` or `$slider`. Now a days, this is being fancy to create variables starting with $ like `$varName`. Most of jQuery guys are used to do this. :-)
- this is appended to `DIV` instantly. It has nothing to do with `hover` here in your case.
- in mouseover, **$slider** is being used and it still contains `$("#divSlider")` only. After mouseover on `<a />` the class `active` will be added there.